# Can I track workspace changes in Perforce?

Tags: continuous-integration, perforce

Our Jenkins job downloads some code from a Perforce server, using a pre-defined workspace. It
sometimes fails with the following error message:

```
Client 'xxxx' can only be used from host 'yyyy'.
```

When I look at the workspace ("client" is an obsolete name for workspace), I see that its settings don't mention host yyyy at all.

I suspect that people (or unknown scripts) change the workspace's settings, do some work and then change them back. If a Jenkins job is scheduled to run during that time, it fails.

How can I determine if I guessed correctly? Are there any logs on the Perforce server which report workspace changes? Maybe some server setting to record all changes to workspaces?

Workspace settings look like something I should be able to track and/or revert using version control; is this really the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, you should set the `locked` option on the client if you don't want anyone else messing with it (and set its `Owner` to be the user who runs the Jenkins job, and ensure that this user is password-protected so that nobody else can impersonate Jenkins).

To track changes to client specs, you can set up a spec depot (just create a depot with `Type: spec`).  This will cause every spec update to be saved in that depot as a revision of a text file, e.g. client `xxxx` will correspond to a text file called `//spec/client/xxxx`.  You can run normal commands like `p4 annotate` on that file to see its change history, and you can pipe old versions of the file into the current client spec by doing, e.g.:

```
p4 print -q //spec/client/xxxx | p4 client -i
```

But again, first and foremost, persistent clients that automation depends on should simply be `locked` so that they can't be sabotaged (intentionally or unwittingly) by other users.